# iframe: removing internal (grey) border

Tags: html, css, iframe, border

I want to embed a pdf-document on my website, but cannot manage to display the document in the iframe without an overwhelmingly useless gray border.

Now I see that this gray border is not always displayed when embedding a pdf-document, but in my example as you can see in the picture, there is a large border withing the iframe, next to the pdf-page I actually would like to display.

See here what I am talking about: 
[image]

I am using a simple iframe-tag within a div-tag.

Does anybody know if it is possible to remove the grey border ("Border in iframe") or how I can deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The border you see is when the page is not matching the aspect-ratio of the view-port of the Acrobat plugin.

You need to make sure the iFrame and the plugin and the document inside it are all the same width and that the user has not set the page to be shown in some other way such as full height (set in Acrobat Reader preferences)

For now try adding this to the PDF url:

`#view=Fit&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0`

Comment: First of all thank's a lot for the fast response. I have added the parameters to the PDF url as given in your answer, but it has not changed anything. I am trying to look more into the ratio of the view-port regarding the Acrobat plugin.

Comment: Also have a look in your Acrobat reader to see how YOU have set your display - for example to full height instead of full width